# Parsing data in python to json

Tags: python, json, parsing

I need to parse data from into python from a json file. I keep getting the error code
decode error expecting property name enclosed in double quotes.

I'm entering this

```
import json
openJSON = open('buffy.json')
pythonJson = json.load(openJSON)
```

[image: json file]

Comment: You have presumably validated the JSON file at an online validator.

Comment: You have trailing commas after, for example, **"ability": "Slayer",**. They're illegal

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas after each ability. You only need commas if there is another property following it. Because there isn't a property after it and instead a '}', it is erroring.